# Depicting the renormalization group in terms of decimation and rescaling

Tags: condensed-matter, renormalization, phase-transition, ising-model

In [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322749680_Nonequilibrium_critical_phenomena_exact_Langevin_equations_erosion_of_tilted_landscapes) paper, the author is discussing the renormalization group, as done with the Ising model.

Some aspects of the description don't seem to make sense, though I must be misunderstanding something. The figure below is what I will refer to.

1. He says that "Each block-spin defines a new spin variable on a new lattice with four times less variables." (middle of the figure)

How does this middle figure have 4 times less variables? To me, it looks like it has 9 times less variables (left image has 81 total spins, middle image has 9 total spins ("block spins"))...although "spin" is in fact a single variable...so is he referring to other variables?

2. He also says that the new lattice spacing (*3a*) is "twice as big" as the original lattice spacing. Isn't *3a* three times as big as *a*?
3. The author also depicts the rescaling as shrinking the coarse grained lattice (middle) down to the size of an individual spin block (right). But he also says that the rescaling is done "such that the new lattice is identical to the original." Wouldn't the rescaling need to *increase* the size of each block to the original lattice size for the new and old lattices to be identical in size?

[image]

Comment: These look to mostly be typos. The author might have originally intended to show the coarse graining with blocks of 2 x 2 spins, but when making the figure switched to blocks of 3 x 3 spins and overlooked adjusting some of the text accordingly. In terms of rescaling, if you think of this as a formally infinite lattice with an infinite number of neurons (the limit in which phase transitions appear), then to map the coarse-grained lattice back onto the original lattice you need to decrease the length scale by a factor of 3 for the lattices shown.

Comment: Thanks @bbrink The typos idea makes sense. Probably the case. As for the resizing, I see what you mean, but wouldn't that make the middle image the size of only one block spin? Why would the entire coarse-grained version only be rescaled to one of the block spins? Shouldn't it be rescaled to be the same size as the original lattice?

Comment: "Size" here refers to the spatial distances between spins, not number of spins. The middle image shows nine block spins and when you resize the lattice you are not changing the number, just the distance between them (which affects the interactions between block spins in the new Hamiltonian). If you coarse grain *again*, then those 9 block spins become a single block spin. If the image were showing a lattice that initially had only 81 spins, then you couldn't rescale anymore. In an infinite system or larger finite lattice you could rescale again.